# Does wrapping a std::atomic_flag in a getter/setter void its "atomicity"?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Say I have a class that contains a `std::atomic_flag` as private member, exposed through a getter. Something like the following (pseudo-code):

```
class Thing
{
private:

    std::atomic_flag ready = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

public:

    isReady()
    {
        return ready.test_and_set(); 
    }
}
```

My naive question is: does querying the flag through a method turn it into a non-atomic operation, being a function call non-atomic (or is it?)? Should I make my `ready` flag a public member and querying it directly?

Comment: Direct access and access by a function call do not affect the atomic nature of `ready`.  Could you say how you use `ready` as I suspect this may be the real issue?

Comment: @RichardCritten I suppose (mine was just a curiosity, not a real program) another thread could fetch the ready state of Thing by looping over `isReady`, like `while (!isReady()) do_something()`. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it doesn't. The `test_and_set()` operation itself is atomic, so it doesn't matter how deep different threads' call-stacks are.

To demonstrate this, consider the base case where the `atomic_flag` object is "exposed" directly:

```
static atomic_flag flag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

void threadMethod() {

    bool wasFirst = !flag.test_and_set();
    if( wasFirst ) cout << "I am thread " << this_thread::get_id() << ", I was first!"      << endl;
    else           cout << "I am thread " << this_thread::get_id() << ", I'm the runner-up" << endl;
}
```

If two threads enter `threadMethod` - with one thread (`t1`) slightly before the other (`t2`) then we can expect the console output to be the following (in the same order):

```
I am thread t1, I was first!
I am thread t2, I'm the runner-up
```

Now if both threads enter simultaneously, but `t2` is a microsecond ahead of `t1`, but `t2` then becomes slower than `t1` as it writes to stdout, then the output would be:

```
I am thread t1, I'm the runner-up
I am thread t2, I was first!
```

...so the call to `test_and_set` was still atomic, even though the output is not necessarily in the expected order.

Now if you were to wrap `flag` in another method (not inlined, just to be sure), like so...

```
__declspec(noinline)
bool wrap() {
    return !flag.test_and_set();
}

void threadMethod() {

    bool wasFirst = wrap();
    if( wasFirst ) cout << "I am thread " << this_thread::get_id() << ", I was first!"      << endl;
    else           cout << "I am thread " << this_thread::get_id() << ", I'm the runner-up" << endl;
}
```

...then the program would not behave any differently - because the `false` or `true` return `bool` value from `test_and_set()` will still be in each thread's stacks. Ergo, wrapping a `atomic_flag` does not change its atomicity.

Answer (score 5):

The atomicity property of C++ atomics guarantees that an operation can not be broken in the middle. That is, for a second thread observing the atomic, it will either observe the state before the `test_and_set` or the state after the `test_and_set`. It is *not* possible for such a thread to sneak in a `clear` between the `test` and the `set` part.

However, this is only true for the operation itself. As soon as the `test_and_set` call has completed, all bets are off again. You should always assume that the thread executing the `test_and_set` might get pre-empted *immediately* after finishing that instruction, so you can not assume that any instruction executing after the `test_and_set` will still observe the same state.

As such, adding the function call does not get you into trouble here. Any instruction following the atomic one must assume that the state of the atomic variable could have changed in the meantime. Atomics take this into account by providing interfaces that are designed in a special way: For example, `test_and_set` returning the result of the test, because obtaining that information through a separate call would not be atomic anymore.

Answer (score 2):

No, the `isReady()` method would work exactly the same as direct `test_and_set()` call, that is atomically.